# Posting contents of UILabel to Facebook?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

Just dabbling with some iOS stuff and would like to integrate Facebook (and eventually twitter).

I have a UILabel which randomly changes and would like to post the contents of it to Facebook. Can anyone help on how to achieve this? Perhaps point me in the direction of resources? As a newbie I'm finding it difficult to find what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get ShareKit: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

Everything is already ready to go and all you have to do is integrate it into your project and add a few lines of code!!!

Comment: Thanks, I've had a read through, looks like it doesn't like ARC though :(

Comment: Yep not yet. Sometime in the future it will. Also, if your project is all arc, you can disable arc for all of ShareKits files. However, this is your best free solution in order to share to the popular social sites easily.